# Simple .htaccess rewrite for single get parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite

```
http://data.example.com/?file=test
```

to

```
http://data.example.com/test
```

via `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /\?file=([^\ &]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?file=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @grandy sorry, there was a stray / in the first condition

Comment: Thanks now it works just fine. URL rewriting and regex is not my world =D